# db.SaveChanges in ForEach causes 'New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have an excel file with about 21000 rows . I imported it into a temp Table in my database.

Now I want to do some conversions on my data and then put them into my main table.

When I do `SaveChanges()` inside a `foreach` I got the following error:

`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session`

When I use it after the `foreach` no error occurs and the table has just 4 records inserted instead of all 21000 records that I expected.

```
    public ActionResult FeedTempdataToMainDB()
    {
        var L = new Leave();
        //  var leaves = new List<Leave>();
        foreach (var item in db.TempLeaves)
        {
            L.Pcode = Int32.Parse(item.Cod);
            var z = int.Parse(item.LT) - 1;
            if (z == 0) L.LT = Leave.LeaveType.Saati;
            else L.LT = Leave.LeaveType.Roozane;
            var o = int.Parse(item.DLT) - 1;
            if (o == 0) L.DLT = Leave.DLType.Estehghaghi;
            if (o == 1) L.DLT = Leave.DLType.Estelaji;
            else L.DLT = Leave.DLType.Bihoghoogh;
            L.LeaveDayStart = item.LeaveDayStart.Old6digToMiladi();
            L.LeaveDayEnd = item.LeaveDayEnd.Old6digToMiladi();
            L.LeaveTimeStart = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeStart);
            L.LeaveTimeEnd = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeEnd);
            L.LeaveDays = int.Parse(item.LeaveDays);
            L.LeaveMinuts = SaatiLengh(item.LeaveMinuts);
            L.RegDate = StringToHour(item.RegTime);
            L.RegDate = item.RegDate.Old6digToMiladi().Date;
            L.RegistrarCode = Int32.Parse(item.RegistrarCode);
            L.HijriYear = L.LeaveDayStart.GetHijriYear();
            var t = IsOk(item.RegTime);
            if (L.DLT == 0 && t == false || L.LT == 0)
            {
                L.Calculate = false;

                L.IsActive = false;
            }
            else { L.Calculate = true; L.IsActive = true; }
            db.Leaves.Add(L);
            db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        //db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("index");
     }
```

Comment: You db has no rows since you did a "new DatabaseContext".  So how can you save something the is empty?

Comment: So why it stores some of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. You declared and created L outside of the loop. Each time you add the same L , only with different data. In the end you have list of the same data  that was created during the last foreach loop cicle.

try this:

```
        foreach (var item in db.TempLeaves)
        {
            var z = int.Parse(item.LT) - 1; 
            var L = new Leave {
                Pcode = Int32.Parse(item.Cod),
                LeaveTimeStart = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeStart),
                LeaveTimeEnd = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeEnd),
                LeaveDays = int.Parse(item.LeaveDays),
                LT = z == 0? Leave.LeaveType.Saati : Leave.LeaveType.Roozane
            };     
            db.Leaves.Add(L);
        }
```

or this

```
        var leaves = new List<Leave>();
        foreach (var item in db.TempLeaves)
        {
            var z = int.Parse(item.LT) - 1; 
            var L = new Leave {
                Pcode = Int32.Parse(item.Cod),
                LeaveTimeStart = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeStart),
                LeaveTimeEnd = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeEnd),
                LeaveDays = int.Parse(item.LeaveDays),
                LT = z == 0? Leave.LeaveType.Saati : Leave.LeaveType.Roozane
            };     
            leaves.Add(L);
        }

        if (leaves.Count > 0)
        {
            db.Leaves.AddRange(leaves);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

if you want to use async save you have to make async action at first.

Comment: Thanks Serge actually i summarized my code here to short my comment here is my code :

Comment: foreach (var item in db.TempLeaves)
            {
                L.Pcode = Int32.Parse(item.Cod);
                var z = int.Parse(item.LT) - 1;
                if (z == 0) L.LT = Leave.LeaveType.Saati;
                else L.LT = Leave.LeaveType.Roozane;
                L.LeaveTimeStart = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeStart);
                L.LeaveTimeEnd = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeEnd);
                L.LeaveDays = int.Parse(item.LeaveDays);
                                   db.Leaves.Add(L);
                   }

Comment: Hi Serge I changed the code as above (beginning) and use db.SaveChangesAsync() in foreach loop now i don't have the error but still table is empty.

Comment: I didn't advise you to use SaveChangesAsync and especially use it inside of the loop. Use my variant 2 it is the most reliable.

Comment: Thanks Serge so much your code worked for me so I updated latest code above

Answer (score 1):

The raison every time that foreach execute the savechnages there is a thread that your not note controlling. Since entity framework is managing  the savechanges function.  You have to execute  your savechnages after the foreach or  use async function.

Comment: Hi Yacine would you please tell me how to use async cause i am beginner in mvc.

Answer (score 1):

here an example for the async:

```
private static async Task<Student> GetStudent()
```

{
Student student = null;

```
using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start GetStudent...");
          
    student = await (context.Students.Where(s => s.StudentID == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync<Student>());
        
    Console.WriteLine("Finished GetStudent...");
}

return student;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

***This Code finally worked:**

```
public ActionResult FeedTempdataToMainDB()
{
    var leaves = new List<Leave>();
    foreach (var item in db.TempLeaves)
    {
        var L = new Leave();
        L.Pcode = Int32.Parse(item.Cod);
        var z = int.Parse(item.LT) - 1;
        if (z == 0) L.LT = Leave.LeaveType.Saati;
        else L.LT = Leave.LeaveType.Roozane;
        var o = int.Parse(item.DLT);
        if (o == 0) L.DLT = Leave.DLType.Estehghaghi;
        if (o == 1) L.DLT = Leave.DLType.Estelaji;
        else L.DLT = Leave.DLType.Bihoghoogh;
        L.LeaveDayStart = item.LeaveDayStart.Old6digToMiladi();
        L.LeaveDayEnd = item.LeaveDayEnd.Old6digToMiladi();
        L.LeaveTimeStart = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeStart);
        L.LeaveTimeEnd = StringToHour(item.LeaveTimeEnd);
        L.LeaveDays = int.Parse(item.LeaveDays);
        L.LeaveMinuts = SaatiLengh(item.LeaveMinuts);
        L.RegDate = StringToHour(item.RegTime);
        L.RegDate = item.RegDate.Old6digToMiladi().Date;
        L.RegistrarCode = Int32.Parse(item.RegistrarCode);
        L.HijriYear = L.LeaveDayStart.GetHijriYear();
        var t = IsOk(item.RegTime);
        if (L.DLT == 0 && t == false || L.LT == 0 && t == false)
        {
            L.Calculate = false;

            L.IsActive = false;
        }
        else { L.Calculate = true; L.IsActive = true; }
        leaves.Add(L);
    }

    if (leaves.Count > 0)
    {
        db.Leaves.AddRange(leaves);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```